# Active link with css color

Tags: php, html, css

I have a filter element to filter data:

http://dualda.com/index.php?option=com_findme&view=info&layout=ranking&interval=7

And here I want the actual "bold" text as well in RED by using CSS. Any ideas?

e.g. this

```
<a class="redlink" href="/index.php?option=com_findme&amp;view=info&amp;layout=ranking&amp;type=playerByActivity&amp;lang=de">Gespielte Spiele</a>
```

Comment: & what have you tried?

Comment: You've got a lot of bold text on that page.  Can you please post some code so we are certain what you want to change?  You'll get a lot more help that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complement your CSS for `redlink` with this:

```
 b .redlink, b .redlink:link, b .redlink:visited {
   color: #EE2B4E;
 }
```

Target the links inside `b` tags and his different states.

Comment: Hello perfect solution. But can you explain to me why this works??

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a color rule in css:

```
a.redlink {
    color: #F00;
}
```

That should do it, unless it's being overridden by another rule.  If you insert CSS like this and you don't see a change, use a tool like FireBug or the code inspector in Chrome to see what CSS rules are being applied to the element and overriding your styles.  You may have to make your rule more specific so that it takes priority and is applied.

You can also experiment with your page using jQuery to set styles on the fly.  It's a great way to try things.

```
$('a.redlink').css({color: "#F00"});
```

I tried this in the console of my browser while viewing your page.  The a tags with `.redlink` changed to red.

Comment: I did it but I gets always overwritten !

Comment: What gets overwritten?  If you add this to your CSS file or a style block on the page, it'll be there.